# error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, libraries, blender

I am not sure if I must ask this in blender stakcexchange or in here. However, the problem is that when I run a custom compiled version of Blender(that wasn't compiled by me), I see this:

```
./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It shows that a library for loading jpeg files is missing. Now I don't have any idea how to fix it? Is it possible to kinda get it manually? I think that the problem is that Ubuntu 15.10 may have upgraded libjpeg to version 7 and deleted version 6.2 files. But that's all I know so far.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`

Comment: @A.B. Thanks. Solved it. My next error is
`./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @AdriansNetlis: The question that I linked should cover any libraries that Blender may need. You can inspect the output of `ldd ./blender` to see a list of all necessary and unsatisfied shared library dependencies (`ldd` is in the package `libc-bin`).

Comment: If the ldd shows a number of 'not founds' then you may want to look for a different build of blender from someone who's on libraries like yours, ie.15.10 wily. The build is likely using libs from trusty's  time, ex.   libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0 (- if your on 15.10 then 16.04 should be your target.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/63018 - those are missing libraries.
http://www.graphicall.org/1167 - this is the Blender build(it seams pretty new, doesn't it?).
So?

Answer (score -3):

Try `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: LOL! It just tells that 0 removed, 0 upgraded, 0 installed, 3 not upgraded.

Comment: -1 This installs `liboost` *development* files, not `libjpeg` *runtime* files.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  To remove the negative reputation points, [edit] your answer, improve it, and drop a note so that I can review my assessment of your answer.  Alternatively, [delete] it altogether and the negative reputation points will be reversed automatically by the system. (I do this too for answers that give me negative reputation points) **;-)**